# Red color clothes for men in Islam

Tags: hadith, practical-islam, source-identification, prophet-muhammad, men

I heard in a bayan that

> Red colour clothes are only permitted for women and not for men in
>   Islam.

Is it correct?

If yes, I need hadith source for this.

What about Pink, Rose, light and dark red coloured clothes?

I.e. which red is disallowed?

Comment: I remember reading long time ago that red was actually a male color whilst blue was a female one. *Red bull* you see.

Answer (score 4):

There are ahadith (hadiths) which allow wearing red clothes and others which prohibit it.

And therefore the middle way -as described in the linked [Fatwa](http://islamqa.info/en/8341)- is not to wear clothes which are pure red but to wear clothes where the red color is mixed with other colors.

I guess for pink and other color shades you will hardly find a hadith.

Here just some examples of the ahadith:

> - It was narrated that Ibn 'Abbas said:    "I was **forbidden to wear red** garments and gold rings, and to recite  Qur'an when bowing."
>
> [Sunan an-Nasa'i](http://sunnah.com/nasai/48/227)
>
> - Narrated Ibn Azib: The Prophet (ﷺ) forbade us to use the **red Mayathir**
>     and to use Al-Qassiy.
>
> [Sahih al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/55)

Al-Mayathir: plural of Maythar, which is a kind of soft timber

Al-Qassy: are clothes mixed with silk lines

> - Narrated Al-Bara:
>
> "I have not seen anyone with hair past his shoulders in a red Hullah more >handsome than the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ). He had hair that would flow on >his shoulders, having broad shoulders, not too short and not too tall."
>
> [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/24/5)
>
> - Bara' (May Allah be pleased with him) reported:
>
> Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) was of medium stature. **I saw him wearing a red
>   mantle**. I have never seen anything more graceful than that.
>
> [Sahih [al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/65) and [Muslim]](http://sunnah.com/muslim/43/122)

And Allah knows best!

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct (the Prophet Mohammed himself wore red clothes)... it's **completely Halal**.
The reason why some say don't wear it, it’s from the **culture itself**... Because usually pink color for the women and it's kind of weird one a man wore one.

Source: I live in Islamic country and I'm a Muslim.

Comment: Any reference for " Prophet Mohammed himself wore red clothes" ?

Answer (score -2):

Check these from the book حلیة المتقین by the great Allameh Majlesi (see [here](http://www.ghadeer.org/books/t_11/hilat001.htm#link4) as for the source, in Persian):

> بهترين رنگها در جامه سفيد است و بعد از آن زرد و بعد از آن سبز و بعد از
>   آن سرخ نيمرنگ و كبود وعدسى ، مكروه است سرخ تيره خصوصا در نماز و پوشيدن
>   جامه سياه كراهت شديد دارد در همه حال ، مگر در عمامه و عبا و موزه و اگر
>   عمامه و عبا هم سياه نباشد بهتر است .

The best of colors for the clothing is white, then yellow and then green, after that light red and ...  and it is discouraged to wear a cloth in dark red especially for Salah and wearing black is strongly discouraged but only in three exceptions ...

> در حديث معتبر منقول است كه حكم بن عتبه بخدمت حضرت امام محمد باقر عليه
>   السلام رفت ، ديد كه جامه سرخ تيره كه بگل كافشه رنگ كرده بودند پوشيده
>   است ، حضرت فرمودند كه در اين جامه چه ميگوئى ؟ حكم گفت كه : چه گويم در
>   چيزى كه شما پوشيده باشيد اما جوانان شوخ كه درميان ما اين جامه را
>   ميپوشند، ما ايشانرا عيب ميكنيم . حضرت فرمود كه زينت خدا را كى حرام
>   كرده است ، بعد از آن فرمود كه باين سبب اين جامه راپوشيده ام كه تازه
>   داماد شده ام .
>
> در حديث حسن از حضرت امام جعفر صادق عليه السلام منقول است كه جامه سرخ
>   تيره پوشيدن كراهت دارد مگر براى نوداماد.

from Imam Baqir and Imam Sadiq peace be upon them is narrated that dark red is discouraged for men but only at their wedding, or right after their wedding.

> از حسن زيّات منقول است كه ديدم حضرت ابيجعفر عليه السلام را كه جامه
>   برنگ گل سرخ پوشيده بودند.

It is narrated that Imam Baqir peace be upon him was wearing cloth in rosy color.

> از حضرت امام جعفر صادق عليه السلام منقول است كه جبرئيل در روز آخر ماه
>   مبارك رمضان بر حضرت رسول صلّى اللّه عليه وآله وسلّم نازل شد بعد از
>   نماز عصر چون به آسمان رفت حضرت رسول صلّى اللّه عليه وآله وسلّم فاطمه
>   را طلب فرمود كه شوهر خود على را بطلب ، پس چون حاضر شدند حضرت اميرالمؤ
>   منين عليه السلام را در جانب راست نشانيد و دستش را گرفت و بردامن خود
>   گذاشت و حضرت فاطمه را در جانب چپ نشانيد را گرفت و بر دامن خود گذاشت پس
>   فرمود كه : ميخواهيد شما را خبردهم به آنچه جبرئيل مرا به آن خبر داد؟
>   گفنتد:بلى يا رسول اللّه ، فرمود كه : جبرئيل گفت كه در قيامت من در جانب
>   راست عرش خواهم بود و خداى تعالى دو جامه بمن پوشاند يكى سبز و ديگرى سرخ
>   برنگ گل ، تو يا على در جانب راست عرش باشى و دو جامه چنين در تو پوشانند
>   پس راوى عرض كرد كه مردم رنگ سرخ چنين را مكروه ميدانند حضرت فرمود كه
>   چون خدا حضرت عيسى را بآسمان برد دو جامه چنين بر او پوشانيد.

Narrated from Imam Sadiq --peace be upon him-- that Gabriel --peace be upon him-- once descended to the holy prophet --peace be upon him and his household-- at the last day of Ramadhan and brought to him two cloths one in green and another in rosy red color. The holy prophet peace be upon him and his household then added that these are the like cloths that Allah brought to Jesus --peace be upon him-- when he was risen to the sky.

Also in a Hadeeth from Imam Baqir --peace be upon him-- the holy prophet --peace be upon him and his household-- told Imam Ali --peace be upon him-- that red is the color of clothing of Satan (Ref. علل الشرائع / ترجمه ذهنى تهرانى، ج‏2، ص:137).

However if I am not mistaken by "dark red" above it is meant "carmine red" (a very reddish red I mean!) not really dark red. Though not certain about it.

Comment: the question was asked in English, would you please be able to translate your answer, for those of us who do not speak other languages!