# Is it acceptable for a Muslim to wear yellow or red coloured dress?

Tags: clothing

I faced a confusing question today. I wore a yellow coloured jersey. So a person in my area told me that it is not acceptable in Islam for a Muslim to wear yellow or red coloured dress.

I didn't know what to say? Is there any strong evidence in Islam about it? Is it a sin?

Comment: Do you mean male and female or male only? [This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8929/red-color-clothes-for-men-in-islam) is related for the later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Things are assumed to be halal unless there is a strong evidence to say it is haram. I have not found evidence that prevents you from wearing any color. There was some ambivalent among scholars about wearing red for men (like JUST RED) but even that is not strong.